# How do I remove the black flash when closing mmenu on iOS7 browsers

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, css, mmenu

I have this plugin: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

It's implemented here: http://ultiuscorp.com/sodemo/demo/horizontal-submenus.html

The only thing I added was making the header fixed.

**In iOS7/Safari or Chrome**:
But, when I am scrolled down and then close the menu there is a "flash" of black and I don't know how to remove it. You can't really see it on a desktop but it's painful to use it on my iPhone.

I have experimented with different z-index levels for each element (like the similar question here [How can I fix the image "flashing" that occurs on my site when I open the mmenu menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437723/how-can-i-fix-the-image-flashing-that-occurs-on-my-site-when-i-open-the-mmenu)) but it was no help.

This issue even happens on the demo page for the plugin itself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/30

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question. Can I compensate you to do custom work on our build to make it work with a simple left, under configuration with the fixed header? I will email you in addition. Thanks.